# Default termination policy of AWS auto scaling group

Tags: amazon-ec2

In an auto scaling group, if there are equal number of instances in multiple availability zones, which availability zone will be selected for terminating instances as per the AWS default termination policy? Is it randomly selected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-termination.html), if you did not assign a specific termination policy to the group, it uses the default termination policy.

In the scenario when an equal number of instances are there in multiple availability zones, Auto Scaling group selects the Availability Zone with the instances that use the oldest launch configuration.

If the instances were launched from the same launch configuration, then the Auto Scaling group selects the instance that is closest to the next billing hour and terminates it.